# Form Hidden Field Substitution

Tags: javascript, forms, expressionengine, hidden-field, safecracker

I'm building a form using Expression Engine's Safecracker module.

One of the the required fields is the Title, which becomes the title of the EE channel entry.

What I'd like to do is set the Title field to be the combined first name and last name fields.

I started with this:

```
<form method="POST" action="#">

<input id="student_first_name" type="text" size="30" name="student_first_name"> 
<br>
<input id="student_last_name" type="text" size="30" name="student_last_name"> 
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="title" value=""/> 

</form>
```

And then added this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#student_first_name').keyup(function() {
        var snamef = $(this);
    });
    $('#student_last_name').keyup(function() {
        var snamel = $(this);
    });
    $("input[name='title']").val(snamel + " " + snamef);
    return false;
});​
```

​I can't get it to work, though: http://jsfiddle.net/tylonius/CY5zJ/4/

Am I missing a step (or just totally doing it wrong?)?

Also, am I possibly working too hard and Safecracker already has this function built in; similar to its live UrlTitle(); function?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

ty

Comment: first set an id on your input element, then use @user1236048's method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better yet, avoid using javascript altogether and just use SafeCracker's [**dynamic_title** parameter](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/safecracker/index.html#dynamic-title).

`dynamic_title="[student_first_name] [student_last_name]"`

Comment: Doh! I had a sneaky suspicion that I was missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood right your question try this:

First set an id on your desired input element, like this :

```
<input type="text" name="title" id="student_title" value=""/>
```

And then :

```
$(function() {  
    changeFunction = function() {
        $('#student_title').val($('#student_first_name').val() + ' ' + $("#student_last_name").val());
    }

    $('#student_first_name').keyup(changeFunction)
    $('#student_last_name').keyup(changeFunction);   
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! It works perfectly, and is much more simple than my initial approach. Thanks so much!

Comment: You could make this even simpler by combining the two keyup listeners in one line, like so: `$('#student_first_name, #student_last_name').keyup(changeFunction);`

Answer (score 1):

user1236048 has the best solution for you but below is a working version of your code

```
$(function() {

    var snamef;
    var snamel;

    $('#student_first_name').keyup(function() {
         snamef = $(this).val();
         $("input[name='title']").val(snamel + " " + snamef);
    });
    $('#student_last_name').keyup(function() {
         snamel = $(this).val();
         $("input[name='title']").val(snamel + " " + snamef);
    });
    return false;
});
```

and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CY5zJ/14/) is the working jsfiddle

Comment: I do prefer the simplified version, but thank you for this as well; it illustrates my initial mistake. Thanks!